# Tag merge request: "adapter" and "adapter-pattern"

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

Tag wiki for [adapter](/questions/tagged/adapter):

> Adapter is a software design pattern that makes several interfaces compatible through a common interface or class.

[adapter-pattern](/questions/tagged/adapter-pattern) has no tag wiki, but its use meets the description given for [adapter](/questions/tagged/adapter). I propose merging these tags.

Comment: Adapter has a whole bunch of other computer-y meanings than just the design pattern. I'm not sure if the usage on SO mirrors that usage or not, but once again, we can't go simply by the tag wiki.

Comment: Why can't we go by the tag wiki? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the tag wikis... are they not meant to clarify the purpose of the tag?

Comment: That's what they are *meant* for, but that doesn't mean they're 100% correct in every case, or that they capture *all possible uses* of the tag.

Comment: Basically I think appending `-pattern` to all of the design pattern tags would clarify things quite a bit. Which is more clear, [tag:adapter] or [tag:adapter-pattern]? [tag:command] or [tag:command-pattern]? Why not have all design pattern tags suffixed with `-pattern` to avoid confusion?

Comment: @GGG: `Why can't we go by the tag wiki?` -- Because sometimes the community co-opts a general tag (or one with multiple meanings) for a meaning that's too specific. Anyone with sufficient rep can make or edit a tag wiki; that doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see, thanks. Perhaps that tag wiki can be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than merge them, the tag wikis should be corrected so that [adapter-pattern](/questions/tagged/adapter-pattern) has an accurate wiki. Since [adapter](/questions/tagged/adapter) is rather generic, however, I am not sure what it should have for a wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure [tag:adapter] should have a wiki at all. Looks like Adapter is a class or interface in some Android code... I think the tag is being used for that mostly.